# Angular2 Error in pushing data to array

Tags: angular

I have a variable declared of a model

```
 private lsName: Projectname.Models.LsModel[];
```

I then call the service to get data and push to this variable

```
 this.SomeDataService.getName().subscribe((lsName: Project.Models.LsModel[]) => {
            this.lsName.push(lsName);
```

But I get the error like: Argument of Type LsModel[] is not assignable to the parameter of type 'LsModel'. Property 'LsData' is missing LsModel[].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `push`, you need to add the items one by one

```
private lsName: Projectname.Models.LsModel[] = [];
```

```
this.SomeDataService.getName().subscribe(
  (lsName: Project.Models.LsModel[]) => {
     lsName.forEach(val => this.lsName.push(lsName));
  });
```

perhaps you just wanted

```
this.SomeDataService.getName().subscribe(
  (lsName: Project.Models.LsModel[]) => this.lsName = lsName));
```

Comment: No, I do not get the data at once. I get 1 row everytime I hit a button. I need all the data which user has selected. If I do like above, the data is lost after each click. I hope I am clear

Comment: Then `(lsName: Project.Models.LsModel[]) => {` should be `(lsName: Project.Models.LsModel) => {`

Comment: With what code? The last example doesn't use `push` at all.

Comment: my code:private lsName: Project.Models.LsModel[]; this.SomeDataService.getLsName().subscribe((lsName: Project.Models.LsModel) => {
            this.lsName.push(lsName);
        });

Comment: lsName: Project.Models.LsModel[]=[];

Comment: I am new to angular2 hence I dis not get what to change in my code?

Comment: Add ` = []` like shown in my answer in the first line.

Comment: Works! I had to add the array index to get the UI side working.  <div class="" *ngFor="let lName of lsName">
                        {{ lName[0].Data }}